# Deploy jBPM project developed in eclipse

Tags: jbpm

I developed a jBPM 5.1 process in eclipce now I want to deploy it in a server, how can I do that? 
I don't know if I have to deploy in jBoss server or if I have to add the jar to jbpm-console, I'm realy lost.

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.2/userguide/ch03.html and run the installer.

The installer will download jBoss As, Guvnor (and jBPM Designer), the JBPM Console, and a demo task service implementation.

In order to run a jBPM process, you need to deploy it to a Guvnor instance (running on a jBoss AS server/instance) and have a jBPM console or other application that jBPM can run inside of.